# external css converted into internal css automatically in reactjs so multiple css files could not be applied

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

used create-react-app but different css are not applied..
 Eg:
Expectation : [see style elements in inspect menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idSwj.png)
Reality:[actually what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdZu8.png)

I don't know why there is always conflict in css+react

I applied only one css here but in actually there were 3 css to be applied but it is not applied correctly.

```
index.js :
```

```js
import "./assets/css/style.css";

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import rootSaga from "./sagas";
import { rootReducer } from "./reducers";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";
//import "./styles/font-awesome.css";
import "font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css";

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware))
);
sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <div id="wrapper">
        <App />
      </div>
    </Provider>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well why would you only import the one CSS file if you need 3? You need to import them all. Also if there are overlapping styles the files you import last will overwrite the previous ones.

Comment: i tried out to import all the css but its not working

Comment: Do you get errors in the console? If you go to Network tab in Chrome dev tools can you see the css filed being loaded?

Comment: no i did not get any errors in console.
yes css fields are being loaded but ts not perfectly applied.